# Use Filter on a protected sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use filter for the header row to enable the users to let them select the data based on the filters. But eventually I have protected the entire sheet in my vba code as below to not let the users mess up or change the data .

Any suggestions on how could I enable the filters and unprotect only the first row of the **Data** worksheet ?

```
 Worksheets("Data").Protect Password:="125393"

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: Let me know if it works with my answer !

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
With ActiveSheet
    .Protect Password:="125393", AllowFiltering:=True
    .EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
End With
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: @Swathi Great !, please remember to mark answer as correct so anyone who has the same doubt can use it